# Remove duplicates from list (algorithm speed)

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, duplicates

I am currently reading [How To Think Like A Computer Scientist](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/list_algorithms.html#index-0) and working through the exercises there. There is a function (remove_adjacent_dups) in the List Algorithm section that I thought I could improve.

Original function:

```
def remove_adjacent_dups(xs):
    """ Return a new list in which all adjacent
        duplicates from xs have been removed.
    """
    result = []
    most_recent_elem = None
    for e in xs:
        if e != most_recent_elem:
            result.append(e)
            most_recent_elem = e

    return result
```

My function:

```
def remove_duplicates(xs):
    """Removes duplicate elements from given list ”xs” """
    result = []
    for e in xs:
        if e not in xs:
            result.append(e)
    return result
```

**remove_adjacent_dups** will only work with a sorted list, so there is an extra operation involved. **remove_duplicates** dosen't care if the sequence is sorted or not, it will remove all duplicates anyway. The thing is, though, if I apply my function to the exercise in the book, it is considerably slower:

***remove_duplicates:***

There are 27336 words in the book. Only 2569 are unique.

That took 0.2556 seconds.

***remove_adjacent_dups:***

There are 27336 words in the book. Only 2569 are unique.

That took 0.0132 seconds. (sorting operation included in this time)

Any one have any idea why *remove_adjacent_dups* is more efficient even though it involves an extra sorting operation and it has one more extra variable *most_recent_elem*?

Comment: Your `remove_duplicates` does not work in its current form. Pls fix the typo. Moreover, the *adjacent* version only has to look at the previous element in each iteration while the *full* version has to consider all previously seen elements. That's why the *adjacent* version is faster. (You can use a `set` to keep track of seen elements to make it better, though)

Comment: Looks like the book does not deserve its title. It totally fails to teach you the concept of the computational complexity.

Comment: @Kit it's me who failed to understand the "in/not in" concept. The book is really quite helpful, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extra variable isn't going to be *that* slow as you would imagine.

In fact, the key is here:

```
if e not in results:
```

If the result is `True`, this is going to be very time-consuming because the *whole* list is iterated once. That says, with a list of only 10 elements and a huge list of 100,000 elements, the time to run `e not in lst` varies *a lot*.

With `remove_adjacent_duplicates`, you're only looking at the last item, so this comparison takes a constant amount of time and does not vary by list length.